# Is there a canonical method to restrict ssh access to certain IP addresses in Unix?

Tags: ssh, osx, freebsd, sshd

I checked `man` pages related to `ssh` on OS X and other systems and tried using `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` files as per [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40779/39640), and `sshd_config` to no avail.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts.allow 
sshd: 192.168.0.4/255.255.255.0
$ cat /etc/hosts.deny 
sshd: ALL
```

In `sshd_config` I tried using `Match` without success (I don't remember exactly the config).

My system is OS X 10.8.5 and I want the `sshd` to permit access from local IP 192.168.0.4/24 or its local name and deny it to all other hosts including the gateway 192.168.0.1.

**Update** The solution proposed below by Stephen Kitt works except for the format `AllowUsers name/pattern@hostname`. This logs the following

```
sshd[31723]: debug1: attempt 6 failures 5 [preauth]
sshd[31723]: debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
sshd[31723]: debug1: auth2_challenge: user=test devs= [preauth]
sshd[31723]: debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam' [preauth]
sshd[31723]: debug1: auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam' [preauth]
sshd[31723]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for invalid user test from 192.168.0.4 port 55680 ssh2 [preauth]
sshd[31723]: error: PAM: authentication error for illegal user test from 192.168.0.4 via 192.168.0.5
sshd[31723]: Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for invalid user test from 192.168.0.4 port 55680 ssh2
sshd[31723]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for test [preauth]
sshd[31723]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
```

Comment: You want to prevent a client from contacting your gateway? Put the access controls on your gateway not on the client

Comment: Please show what you tried, exactly. For example, what lines did you try to put in `sshd_config`?

Comment: @roaima, no, I want the sshd to permit ssh from a local host but deny it from the local gateway

Comment: @Celada, I edited my post

Comment: Please edit your post (a) to show the `Match` configuration you tried but that didn't work, and (b) to include the details of what it is you are trying to do. If you leave those only in the comments it's far too easy for other people to miss those potentially important details. IP addresses of client, network, and gateway would help, including indications of which are (not) allowed where.

Comment: @roaima, I edited my post

Comment: 192.168.0.4/24 is a subnet which includes 192.168.0.1 (and all addresses starting with 192.168.0.). So allowing 192.168.0.4/255.255.255.0 allows 192.168.0.1... When you say you want to allow 192.168.0.4, is it the single host with that address, or some subnet starting at that address?

Comment: @StephenKitt, it is the single host 192.168.0.4. AFAIK, a match for 192.168.0.4 shouldn't allow also .1 . Anyway, if I only use `/etc/hosts.deny` set to ALL, it still permits traffic from all hosts.

Comment: See http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ to check subnet matches. But as you point out, if denying ALL doesn't deny anything, something else is wrong as well... Do you really have no idea what `Match` statements you tried?

Comment: @StephenKitt, I'd expect a longer more specific match, not just the subnet. I don't remember what I tried with `Match`. How would you write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `Match`, if you wish to allow logging in from a single host, the following works for me (in `sshd_config`):

```
AllowUsers *@192.168.0.4
```

It only allows users logging in from 192.168.0.4, using any login on the target. You can replace `*` with a specific login if you wish, and specify multiple patterns separated by spaces; so for example:

```
AllowUsers user1@192.168.0.4 user2@192.168.0.4
```

Comment: I tested this using user names and patterns (wildcards) for the user part and hostnames and IP addresses for the host part. It works fine except for the format name/pattern@hostname. The hostnames are resolvable, but the system refuses the connection. The log is too long for this comment, but you can try `LogLevel DEBUG`.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the log; if you're looking for answers with hostname filtering you should edit your question anyway, since it currently only mentions IP addresses.

Comment: I edited the post as suggested

Comment: The hostname in your `AllowUsers` line has to match the reverse lookup for the machine you're connecting from. What does `host 192.168.0.4` output when run on the machine you're connecting **to**?

Comment: `host 192.168.0.4
4.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record` but it seems `host` works differently in OS X as per the man page. I do ping the host that initiates the ssh session by name, so it is resolved.

Comment: Your ping indicates that it resolves going from the hostname to the IP address, but for `AllowUsers` to work the reverse must also be true; that's what `host` checks.

Comment: Is there any way to disable the reverse lookup? Or can you suggest a workaround? I tried `UseDNS no` to no avail. I'm setting this up in a local network.

Comment: You need reverse lookup if you want to use a hostname in `AllowUsers`; the incoming connection is only identified by its originating IP address, so `sshd` needs to do a reverse lookup to compare the corresponding hostname with the hostname given in the configuration. As a workaround you could try adding the host in `/etc/hosts`, as a single line with `192.168.0.4 hostname`...

Comment: Adding the host to `/etc/hosts` works, thanks. Still, I don't select this answer for the time being as others may come up with better solutions.

Comment: @1.61803 one year later, it looks like no-one came up with a better solution...